# Difference of regex in python and google app script (backend engine related?)

Tags: javascript, python, regex, google-apps-script, regex-group

I tried the same regular expression both in python (3.6, jupyter notebook) and Google app script, but it seems like "non-capturing group" is not working in the app script case.

```
# python script:
import re
text='<a class=""email"" href=""mailto:SOisAwesome@hello.edu"">'
regex='(?:<a class=""email"" href=""mailto:)(.+?@hello\.edu)(?:"">)'
match=re.search(regex,text)
print(match.group(1))
# result is 'SOisAwesome@hello.edu'

// Google app script
function myFunction() {
  string='<a class=""email"" href=""mailto:SOisAwesome@hello.edu"">'
  regex=new RegExp('(?:<a class=""email"" href=""mailto:)(.+?@hello\.edu)(?:"">)')
  Match=regex.exec(string)
  Logger.log(Match[1])
  // result is 'a class=""email"" href=""mailto:SOisAwesome@hello.edu'
}
```

If I am not mistaken, regular expression engine in Google app script should support non-capturing groups (referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines, I suppose I should be looking at "JavaScript (ECMAScript)" and "Shy groups"?), can anyone explain what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to use `\\` before `.` in the GAS regex declaration, as the literal backslash forms a regex escape sequence.

Now, **it seems that GAS non-capturing group implementation is buggy.**

If you run your regex in GAS and print the `Match` object, you will see

```
[18-01-26 08:49:07:198 CET] [<a class=""email"" href=""mailto:SOisAwesome@hello.edu"">, 
a class=""email"" href=""mailto:SOisAwesome@hello.edu, "">]
```

That means, the *non-capturing group got "merged" with the first capturing group skipping the first char*.

Here are some more experiments:

```
Logger.log(new RegExp("(?:;\\w+):(\\d+)").exec(";er:34")); // = null, expected [;er:34, 34]
Logger.log(new RegExp("(?:e\\w+):(\\d+)").exec(";er:34")); // = null, expected [er:34, 34]
Logger.log(new RegExp("(?:\\w+):(\\d+)").exec(";er:34"));  // =  [er:34, 34], as expected
```

To fix the issue, you may remove the non-capturing parentheses, as `\d` = `(?:\d)`.

Comment: Oh I just realized \w has to be \\w in GAS! Thanks a lot for pointing that out! May I ask why is that (is there any convention / backend engine related reason?)?

(somehow it contradicts with https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en)

Comment: But somehow both 
Logger.log(new RegExp("\\.").exec(".")); 
and 
Logger.log(new RegExp("\.").exec("."));
Match the dot! This is very confusing!

Comment: @Matthew A regex escape sequence is a combination of a *literal* backslash and some symbol(s) after it. A `"\w"` is a `w` because a single backslash is used to define escape sequences like `\n` (newline), `\r` (carriage return), `\t` (tab), etc. Thus, you must use ``\\w`` to match any word char and not `w`. A `"\."` is equal to `"."`, and a dot matches any char but a line break char, thus both `"\\."` and `"\."` match a dot, but `"\\."` will never match `§` and `"\."` will.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification! So it seems like all the \ (as in python case) should be replaced with \\ in GAS? Is there any particular background reason (convention / backend engine related) for this difference?

To illustrate such differences, 
Logger.log(new RegExp('\w+').exec('abcsw')); matches w,
Logger.log(new RegExp('\\w+').exec('abcsw')); matches abcsw

Comment: And thanks for your answer again! It really helps!

By removing the non-capturing parenthesis, it works now!

  string='<a class=""email"" href=""mailto:SOisAwesome@hello.edu"">'
  regex=new RegExp('<a class=""email"" href=""mailto:(.+?@hello\\.edu)"">')
  Match=regex.exec(string)
  Logger.log(Match[1]) // return 'SOisAwesome@hello.edu'

Comment: @Matthew *Is there any particular background reason (convention / backend engine related) for this difference?* - *`a single backslash is used to define escape sequences like \n (newline), \r (carriage return), \t (tab), etc.`* and `a regex escape sequence is a combination of a *literal* backslash and some symbol(s) after it.` A literal backslash is defined with  two backslashes in the string literal.